# Installing amdgpu-pro on Ubuntu 18.10 has broken apt E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I tried following this guide to install the amdgpu-pro drivers on Ubuntu 18.10 however the install failed saying the drivers are for 18.04 only.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-linux

Now apt has compltely borken when I try to run apt upgrade I get the following error message:

```
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-4A1LcU/03-amdgpu-core_19.20-812932_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` however this returns a large list of dependency errors because `Package amdgpu-core is not installed`.

I then tried `apt install -f` to fix the issue but got the error:

```
ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-core_19.20-812932_all.deb (--unpack):
 new amdgpu-core package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-core_19.20-812932_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried `apt autoremove` to clean this up but I get the error:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I ran that command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and get yet more errors:

```
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-core_19.20-812932_all.deb ...
ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-core_19.20-812932_all.deb (--unpack):
 new amdgpu-core package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-core_19.20-812932_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I seem to be stuck in a loop that I can't get out of. Doe's anyone know what I need to do so I can get this removed and apt working again?

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get --purge remove /path/to/amdgpu-core_19.20-812932_all.deb`

Comment: @Fanatique no, however that file doesn't exist on my system. I used the amdgpu-pro-install -y script from the AMD driver tarball which contains over 100 different.deb files in it but none with that name. https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r9-series/amd-radeon-r9-300-series/amd-radeon-r9-380

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by:

step 1: sudo dpkg --configure -a

step 2: sudo dpkg -P *error-packages*(the error packages you  can see from step 1)

in my case, they are

```
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0:amd64
 libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64
 libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:amd64
 gst-omx-amdgpu
 glamor-amdgpu:amd64
 libllvm9.0-amdgpu:amd64
 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64
 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64
 libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64
 libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64
 mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
 mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64
 libdrm-amdgpu-common
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0:amd64
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64
 libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64
 libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64
 libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64
 libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64
```

Step 3: sudo apt autoremove

Then the dependency problem should be gone.